# How to dynamically create a string in an html tag

Tags: html, reactjs, string, twitter-bootstrap, string-interpolation

I need to create a **table** dynamically, this table has three accordion levels (unfolding line) so I need to assign an **id** to each of my `<tr>` tags for bootstrap's accordion functionality to work properly.

I can have an infinite number of `<tr>` so I would like to create my `<tr>` in the following way:

- I read my data received with a .map
- For each read data I get the current index in the map function
- In my html tag `<tr>` I create my id with a known string to which I add the index by an interpolation.

To do this I wrote the following code:
The return of this function completes an already created table by creating the `<tr>` of the `<tbody>`

```
function renderTableData() {
        if(data?.tableData){
            return data.tableData.map((currentData, index) => {
                return (
                    <>
                        <tr key={nanoid()} data-toggle="collapse" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#main-accordion${index}">
                            <td>{currentData.someField}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr className="collapse accordion-collapse" id="main-accordion${index}">
                            //Another <tr> which will contain my first nested accordion
                        </tr>
                    </>
                )
        })} else{return undefined}
    }
```

As you can see in the code above I try to create my **id** in the following way:    `tag-property="#name_id${index}"`

But the interpolation is not done and the string created is: "#main-accordion${index}"

This gives me the following error:

> ```
> Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document':
> '#main-accordion${index}' is not a valid selector.
> ```

Does anyone know how to make an interpolation of this type in a property of an html tag? I really don't see how to do it, any help would be great

Comment: Does this answer your question? [template literals in jsx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49735097/template-literals-in-jsx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) but are using double quotes ("") instead of backticks (``)

if I understood your question correctly, replace this piece of code

```
 data-bs-target="#main-accordion${index}"
```

with

```
data-bs-target={`#main-accordion${index}`}
```

JSX values must be an expression or quoted JSX text, so thats why you have to wrap the backticks in curly brackets

Comment: Yes it was my issue, thanks for the right syntax